# How to check if symbolic link exists no matter where it's pointing to

Tags: ansible

I am trying this YML code:

```
- name: Check links
  file: name=/usr/local/bin/zsh state=link
```

But it's always failed with message: `src and dest are required for creating links`. What I'm trying to do is just checking that the link path exists. I'm not intending to create it if doesn't exist.

Is there any Ansible-idiomatic ways to do this?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Therefore you could use the stat module:
[stat](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/collections/ansible/builtin/stat_module.html)

```
- stat: path=path_to_file
  register: links
- debug: msg="link exists"
  when: links.stat.islnk is defined and links.stat.islnk
```

The [documentation](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/collections/ansible/builtin/stat_module.html#return-stat/islnk) says: `islnk` tells you if the path is a symbolic link

Comment: The documentation states that will only tell you if the file exists.  to check if it is a link you need to do "when: links.stat.islnk is defined and links.stat.islnk"

Comment: Notice that the playbook will not stop in this case.. but continue executing.

Comment: instead of `links.stat.islnk is defined` you can use `links.stat.exists`

Comment: to check the link is broken or really work, u could use `links.stat.readable` or `links.stat.executable`

Comment: @mumubin careful. Those attributes are not trustable: if the task is running with `become: no` and the target linked file have no READ permission, then the test will fail!

Comment: To check if the link is broken or not, be sure to use `follow: yes` on the `ansible.builtin.stat` module! Then, just test if `f.stat.exists` ;)